# TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined Mobx React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

Mobx giving me this error, and I don't know what is going on, there is no error in my code, what I make wrong? I tried so much fix this problem, hours and hours, someone knows what wrong I do??

stores/index.ts

```
import ProductStore from './product.store';

class RootStore {
    products: ProductStore;

    constructor() {
        this.products = new ProductStore();
    }
}

const store = new RootStore();

export {RootStore, ProductStore};

export default store;
```

stores/product.store.ts

```
import {WalmartApi} from '../api';
import {action, makeAutoObservable, runInAction} from 'mobx';

export default class ProductStore {
    products = [];

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    @action
    getProducts = async (searchQuery: string): Promise<void> => {
        const snapshot = await WalmartApi.getProductsBySegment(searchQuery);

        console.log({snapshot});

        runInAction(() => {
            this.products = snapshot;
        });
    };
}
```

hooks/userStores.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {MobXProviderContext} from 'mobx-react';
import store from '@stores';

export const useStores = (): typeof store => {
    return React.useContext(MobXProviderContext).rootStore;
};
```

screens/Home.tsx

```
const {products} = useStores();

    const onInit = () => {
        products.getProducts('Playstation5');
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        onInit();
    });
```

Comment: To use store from the context you need to pass them to the provider first, maybe you forgot that part? `<Provider {...stores}>` etc. But at the same time, you are already using singletones, you don't even need context and all of that.

Comment: I not forgot, see my App.tsx:

`import React from 'react';
import {Routes} from './routes';
import {Provider as MobxProvider} from 'mobx-react';
import store from './stores';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <MobxProvider store={store}>
            <Routes />
        </MobxProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
`

Comment: what is **singletones**? I don't need context and all of that? what you mean when you said **all of that**?